# Nginx Serving static from spring boot war

Tags: spring, tomcat, nginx, spring-boot, static-content

I built a spring boot application, I have thus one app.war file that contains an embedded tomcat and my application itself.

Here's my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sub.domain.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090/index;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|jpg|png|css|html|gif|pdf)$ {
            root /path/to/app/app.war
            expires 30d;
    }
}
```

The site is up an running at sub.domain.com, however the static content is not loaded..

How can I make this work?

Comment: You need to point your `root` somewhere so the server know's where to look, just under your `server_name`. (`root /path/to/sub.domain.com/html;`). This is usually placed in `/var/www/....`

Comment: I tried both with path/to/app and path/to/app/app.war, both yield 502 bad gateway.

Comment: And what's in your `/var/log/nginx/error.log`?

Comment: 2016/08/26 03:53:28 [error] 30301#0: *7318 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: sub.domain.com request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8090/index", host: "sub.domain.com"

Comment: Ok, I later rechecked, the 'connection refused' was due to a corrupt .war. It is working now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made it work, easy enough

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sub.domain.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://domain.com:8090/;
    }

    location ~* \.(svg|js|jpg|png|css|html|gif|pdf)$ {
            proxy_pass              $scheme://domain.com:8090/$request_uri;
            proxy_redirect  off;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
            expires 30d;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Still not working, i'm using jar file from spring boot with the static folder url /static.